# Interpretation of the $K$-groups of a $C^*$-algebra.

Tags: homology-cohomology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I'm learning K-theory of $C^*$-algebras after studying algebraic topology and (co-)homology theories for topological spaces (especially singular and cellular homology, but I'm not familiar with topological K-theory in general).
For topological spaces, there are interpretations what i.e. singular homology measures ($H_0$ measures the number of holes in the space and so forth).

> Now I want to know how to interpret $K_0(A)$ and $K_1(A)$ of a $C^*$-algebra $A$.

**Definitions.** For $K_0$ I know the following definition:

1. For a unital $C^*$-algebra A: Let $P_{\infty}(A)=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} P_n(A)$, where $P_n(A)=\{p\in M_n(A): p^2=p^*=p\}$ (and $P_n\hookrightarrow P_{n+1}$ for all n in the canonical way), endowed with $$\bigoplus :P_{\infty}(A)\times P_{\infty}(A)\to P_{\infty}(A),\; (p,q)\mapsto diag_{m+n}(p,q)$$ for $p\in P_m(A), q\in P_n(A)$. Endow $P_{\infty}(A)$ with an equivalence relation: For $p\in P_m(A), q\in P_n(A)$ let $p \sim q:\iff $ there exists a $v\in M_{n,m}(A)$ such that $p=v^*v$ and $q=vv^*$. Set $D(A):=P_{\infty}(A)/\sim$ and define $K_0(A)$ as the Grothendieck group of the abelian monoid $(D(A),\bigoplus)$.

   2. For $A$ nonunital: We have a split exact sequence $$0\to A  \xrightarrow{i} A^+\xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{C}\to0$$ where $A^+$ is the one-point unitization of $A$, $i$ is the canonical embedding and $\pi(a+\lambda 1)=\lambda$. It is $K_0(A):=\ker (K_0(\pi))$.

For $K_1$ I know the following definition:

$K_1(A):=U_{\infty}(A^+)/\sim $, where: $U_{\infty}(A^+)=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} U_n(A^+)$, $U_n(A^+)=\{u\in M_n(A^+): u^*u=uu^*=1\}$ and for $u\in U_m(A^+), v\in U_n(A^+)$ let $u \sim v:\iff $ there exists a $k\ge max\{m,n\}$ such that $u\oplus 1_{k-m}$ is homotopic to $v\oplus 1_{k-n}$. $\oplus$ is defined analogously as above: $$\bigoplus :U_{\infty}(A^+)\times U_{\infty}(A^+)\to U_{\infty}(A^+),\; (u,v)\mapsto diag_{m+n}(u,v)$$ for $u\in U_m(A^+), v\in U_n(A^+)$.

**Ideas/problems** -I guess that $K_1(A)$ counts the number of path connected components of the unitaries $U_{\infty} (A^+)$, since a homotopy between such elements is a continuous path connecting them. Is it correct?

-I'm stuck to give a suitable interpretation for $K_0(A)$, if that is possible. I would appreciate your ideas here.

Regards.

**Edit**: I have found this very similar question now and there is a partial answer [What properties of a C*-algebra are reflected in their $K_0$ groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202428/what-properties-of-a-c-algebra-are-reflected-in-their-k-0-groups?rq=1)

Comment: As for $K_0$, to cite wikipedia: "The functor $K_0$ takes a ring $A$ to the Grothendieck group of the set of isomorphism classes of its finitely generated projective modules, regarded as a monoid under direct sum." Does that help?

Comment: @MaoWao AT first thanks for your comments. I took the definition of $K_1(A)$ from the book "An introduction to $K$-theory for $C^*$-algebras" and I don't see why this definition isn't correct. And for $K_0$: I know that there is a equivalent definition of $K_0$ in terms of finitely generated projective modules, as you stated ( but it's a purely algebraic definition). However, for all the properties of $K_0$ as stability, half-exactness and so forth and to work with $K_0$ for $C^*$-algebras, it's better to consider a "more analytic definition", I guess.

Comment: Furthermore the definition in terms of finitely generated projective modules doesn't simplify the interpretation, I guess.

Comment: You're right about $K_1$. Both definitions give the same result because $K_1(\mathbb{C})=0$. Concerning $K_0$: There is a similar result using $C^\ast$-modules instead of plain algebraic modules, if you want a more analytical version.

Comment: Swan-Serre theorem relates projective modules over $C(X)$ to vector bundles on $X$, and this should give you an interpretation of $K_0$ as a noncommutative generalization of the "group of stable isomorphism classes of complex vector bundles".

Comment: Also, note that $K_0(A)$ can be defined by the first fundamental group of $\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A)$ with basepoint $1$.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I'm asking this because: When I'm calculating $K$-theory of $C^*$-algebras, I don't have a feeling about possible solutions for the $K$-groups (of a $C^*$-algebra). If you can give me an advice to get a feeling for that, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answers your question: We know that the $K$-groups are abelian. And in fact, every pair $(G_0,G_1)$ of countable abelian groups occurs as $(K_0(A),K_1(A))$ for some $C^*$-algebra $A$. Furthermore, the $K$-groups of a separable $C^*$-algebra are neccesarily countable.